# Will deleting the DatabaseChangeLog table row revert my changes?

Tags: database, oracle, liquibase

We manage our migrations through liquibase. One of my colleagues ran the migrations of an upgraded version of the service that is deployed and now the database and the service are not in sync. The changes were that two of the columns were dropped. I can see the changes in the DatabaseChangeLog table in the oracle. 
If I have to quickly revert it should I simply delete the changeset that Dropped those columns and will that add the column back to the database or not?

Answer (score 4):

No, if the columns have been dropped, then they are dropped, and any data that was in those columns has been lost. If you want to re-add the columns, you would need to add a new changeset to the changelog *file* to re-add those columns, and then run `liquibase update` to create the columns. It *may* be possible to use the `liquibase rollback` command to un-do the changes, but in order for that to work the changesets that dropped the columns would need to have saved the data somewhere else, and then have a way to restore that saved data. I'm guessing you don't have that - but check if the changelog file has a `<rollback>` section in each of the two changesets.

The DATABASECHANGELOG table and the rows in it are just keeping track of which changesets in the changelog file have been deployed to that database.

[This page on the liquibase website](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/core-concepts/index.html) is pretty good at explaining some of the concepts. If there is still something unclear, the Liquibase team would like to get feedback. The best way to provide documentation feedback is by filing an issue at https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase.github.com/